# How to read content of byte[] (PDF endcoding 1.4) in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, pdf-generation

I convert a `partialView to byte[]` then export PDF file. But, I want to read `byte[]` before export to PDF.

I've tried `Base64,Encoding UTF-8`.

[image]

It isn't Content I want. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes *not* adding code as a screenshot and using proper language.

Comment: *"It isn't Content I want."* - It looks like a plain PDF. Why isn't it what you want? What do you want instead?